# How do I convert array of Objects to one Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an array of objects:

```
[ 
  { key : 'a', value1 : 'a1', value2 : 'a2' },
  { key : 'b', value1 : 'b1', value2 : 'b2' }
];
```

How do I convert it into the following ? 
**It would be great to achieve this with lodash.**

```
{
  a: { value1: 'a1', value2 : 'a2' }
  b: { value1: 'b1', value2 : 'b2' }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by LODASH

`const res = _.chain(array).keyBy('key').mapValues( v => _.omit(v, 'key')).value()`

Comment: if I wanted to undo this conversion with lodash too, return to the original array of object.
can you help with that please.

Comment: @MohammadShehab Yes you can do that too. 


`const result = _.map(res, (v, key) => ({ key, ...v }))`

You can return to the original array by doing the above code one

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array.reduce` function:

```
const res = arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
    const {key, ...newO} = o; 
    return {...acc, [o.key]: newO};
  },
  {},
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could destructure the object and map new objects. Finally assign the spreaded objects to a single object.

```js
const
    array = [{ key : 'a', value1 : 'a1', value2 : 'a2' }, { key : 'b', value1 : 'b1', value2 : 'b2' }],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...array.map(({ key, ...o }) => ({ [key]: o })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Map the array of objects to an array of [key, rest], where the rest is the original object without the key, and convert to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`, or lodash's `_.fromPairs()`.

```js
const array = [{ key : 'a', value1 : 'a1', value2 : 'a2' }, { key : 'b', value1 : 'b1', value2 : 'b2' }]

const result = Object.fromEntries(array.map(({ key, ...rest }) => [key, rest]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```js
const output = {};
[ 
  { key : 'a', value1 : 'a1', value2 : 'a2' },
  { key : 'b', value1 : 'b1', value2 : 'b2' }
].forEach(row => output[row.key] = { value1: row.value1, value2: row.value2 });
```

Comment: I did it like this .. but the number of values could change so I want something more dynamic